# quick simple product creation form

Tags: configurable-product, adminform, magento1.9.3.1

We are using 1.9.3.1 installations on 3 different domains. On one installation the quick simple product creation form disappeared suddenly. I have no clue why. Some modules are different. I can not define which module is causing the trouble. I didn't install them.

No error message. The configurable products and attributes looking correct. It was working previously.

Any idea how and where I can start debugging the issue?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: Install this extension and find the conflict module https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modules-conflict-detector.html

Comment: Thanks. Installed  this extensions and It shows an conflict.DerMod & DerModPro were disabled. Enabled it and the quick simple product cragtion form is back again. Hopefully nothing else will not work now after enabling this modul(s) again.

Comment: Always Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the log files in var/log folder:
**system.log
exception.log**

If you cannot find anything turn on the error reporting in index.php in the root folder by removing the hash tag # on line 71 in the latest Magento version 1.9.3.4:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

replace with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You must get then an clear error message on the page where you have the issue and maybe you can see exactly what is causing it.

Comment: Thanks, did not help. If i turn it on, there is no error message visible. I enabled the debug function as well. No result. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the SCP extension (Simple Configurable Product). Uninstall it to see if that is the problem.

Comment: Could be that it was installed in the past. But right now not. Could it be that something is left in the database after uninstalling?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Anyways, happy to see you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. 
I Installed the conflict module and this extensions shows an conflict. DerMod & DerModPro were disabled. Enabled it and the quick simple product creation form is back again. Hopefully nothing else will not work now after enabling this modul(s) again.

Thx
Markus